# Facebook Page Private Replies and Chat Bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created a page private reply app and its working as expected . I have the page subscription with feeds to the webhook on this app.

Now, I have created another app for Chat bot , but the app is not working. I want to know if both of them can work at the same time or I have to crate a single app which will handle both of these ?

Comment: Interesting, I still don't know if these two are supposed to exist in totally different spaces!